# How to setup VS Code for formatting line breaking symmetrically for Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatter, autopep8

Original code

```
            job.create_common_job_log_line(message=message, model_id=model_id, product_id=product.id)
```

This is how it formatted my code which is extremely ugly

```
            job.create_common_job_log_line(
                message=message, model_id=model_id, product_id=product.id)
```

I expect

```
            job.create_common_job_log_line(
                message=message, model_id=model_id, product_id=product.id
            )
```

or

```
            job.create_common_job_log_line(
                message=message, 
                model_id=model_id, 
                product_id=product.id
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use the formatting provided by "**black**" in settings.json file: (VS Code uses 'autopep8' for formatting by default.)

```
 "python.formatting.provider": "black",
 "editor.formatOnSave": true,
```

[image]

Reference: [Formatting in Vs Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting).